# Superclass Point - Subclass Line? Can anyone tell me how to make the subclass line use the x and y declared in class Point?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, subclass, superclass

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Point {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   int x;

   int y;

public void ans() {

       System.out.println("Enter a value for x: ");
       x = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a value for y: ");
        y = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your Point is: "+ "(" +x+ "," +y+ ")");

   }
}
```

LINE CLASS!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Line extends Point {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Point point = new Point();

    int x = point.x;

    int y= point.y;

    int x1;
    int y1;

    int[] A= {x1,y1};
    int[] B= {x,y};

    public void add(){


        System.out.println("Enter a value for x1; ");
        x1 = scan.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Enter a value for y1; ");
        y1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("");
        ans();

        System.out.println("Your Line is: "+ "(" +x+ "," +y+ ")" +"(" +x1+ "," +y1+ ")");
    }   


}
```

In the Output it asks for declaring x and y values again!

Comment: Make your x & y protected in Point class. Or the proper way is to implement a getter/setter for x & y...

Comment: Can u show me how to!? 
I'm a beginner! xC

Comment: A Line is not a Point. It shouldn't extend Point in the first place. A line (or rather, a segment) **has** 2 points.